# Error when trying to install app in site with bench for ERPNEXT

Tags: mariadb, erpnext

I followed this tutorial [Creating an App](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eCAMPcl7NKc&t=305s) step by step after going through the whole installation process line by line from [Turning a mac into a Frappe](https://github.com/frappe/bench/wiki/Turning-a-Mac-into-a-Frappe-Framework-Developer-Machine).

All goes well in the tutorial until I actually try to install the app with the command `bench --site meeting install-app meeting`, whereby I get this error

> Table `9034ff9e2b8f00b4.tabdefaultvalue` doesn't exist.

Even after going through the database on the terminal, I found that the table really does not exist. In fact no table exists at all.
I've followed many posts discussing a similar error, but none of their solutions have worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Your site wasn't created correctly. A few things that you can verify that the site is properly created:

- Check if you have a site name listed in **sites/currentsite.txt**
- There should be a folder with the site name under sites as well **sites/[site_name]/**
- The file **sites/[site_name]/site_config.json** should be there and contain the db name

If after verifying, everything is fine (i.e. the site is created correctly) then
it'll be harder to say what is the error without a log. You can run `bench new-site abc` again and post the log either in the forum on here.

There is a discussion on ERPNext's forum on this error https://discuss.erpnext.com/t/table-a46003081c-tabdefaultvalue-doesnt-exist/9579.